# Why did Isaac’s wife did not like the Hettite women?

Tags: genesis

Why did Isaac’s wife did not like the Hettite women? Genesis 27:46

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you take the Tour (below) you will see how Qs on Hermeneutics should function. They need to have enough substance for us to "get our teeth into", so at the least, the verse in question needs to be quoted (and translation ref. given). Then an explanation as to why there seems to be a problem with the verse needs to be stated, or, if there's no problem, the point in the verse that needs explaining, and why it needs explaining. It is the verse given that has to be examined. What needs sorting out with this verse? Can you enlarge, please?

Answer (score 2):

Rebekah disapproved of Esau's marriage to the Hittite/Hettite women because they made life bitter of her and Isaac. In the previous chapter we find:

> When Esau was forty years old, he took to wife Judith the daughter of
> Be-e′ri the Hittite, and Bas′emath the daughter of Elon the Hittite;
> and they made life bitter for Isaac and Rebekah. (26:34-35)

The Bible does not specify the ways in which these women acted to cause their parents-in-law pain, but [rabbinical tradition](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5846-esau) says:

- They were godless and caused Esau to stay away from his home for many months.
- Grief at the idolatrous practices of Esau's wives caused Isaac's blindness.
- Possibly influenced by his wives, Esau spent most of his days visiting the shrines of idols, which vexed his father even more than his mother.

These traditions were not preserved until much later, so we cannot be certain of their veracity. However it is certainly the case that Isaac and Rebekah expected their sons to marry within the clan. We know this from the fact that (in Ch. 28) Isaac advises Jacob to marry one of the daughters of Laban, and that Esau himself later marries one of the daughters of Ishmael in order to please his parents.

**So we can conclude that Rebekah (and Isaac as well) disapproved of  Esau's wives because they wanted Esau to marry within their extended family, not among their new neighbors, whose ways were foreign to them. Rebekah and Isaac may also have sensed that these women were a bad influence on Esau, leading him to stay away from home and tempting him into godlessness and/or idolatry.**

Answer (score 0):

Esau, who was always interested in earthly attractions, took two wives of the daughters of Heth.  They were worshipers of false gods, and it was because of their idolatry that both Isaac and Rebecca felt bitter grief.

As the Bible records:

> <sup>34</sup> And Esau was forty years old when he took to wife Judith
> the daughter of Beeri the Hittite, and Bashemath the daughter of Elon
> the Hittite: <sup>35</sup> Which were **a grief of mind** unto Isaac and
> to Rebekah. (Genesis 26:34-35, KJV)

It may help to understand exactly who Heth was.

> And Canaan begat Sidon his first born, and Heth, (Genesis 10:15, KJV)

As a son of Canaan, Heth was of the line that Noah had cursed, and had said would be a servant of his brethren.

> <sup>25</sup> And he said, **Cursed be Canaan**; a servant of servants
> shall he be unto his brethren. <sup>26</sup> And he said, Blessed be
> the LORD God of Shem; and Canaan shall be his servant. <sup>27</sup>
> God shall enlarge Japheth, and he shall dwell in the tents of Shem;
> and Canaan shall be his servant. (Genesis 9:25-27, KJV)

In taking this step, Esau had broken one of the conditions of the covenant which forbade the intermarriage of God's people with the unbelievers.  For Rebekah, it was especially disheartening that, in spite of Esau's indifference to spiritual things, Isaac intended to give him the birthright blessing.  It is likely that her favoritism toward Jacob, contrasted with the unsatisfactory marriages of Esau, caused Rebekah to find fault with Esau's wives and consider them as one source of her troubles.

Comment: The rule against intermarriage was not yet in force. So that alone seems not have been sufficient reason. But clearly Esau's parents preferred a Hebrew woman and saw Esau's choice as ill-advised. Note that in the next generation both Judah and Joseph, the forefathers of the most important Israelite tribes, intermarried. So did Moses.

Comment: @DanFefferman Why do you think "The rule against intermarriage was not yet in force"?  What was it that Abraham charged his servant Eliezer with regarding finding a wife for Isaac?  Was he not the patriarch of the family, and establishing a principle which his family should follow?